# Регулярное выражение вида "ZZ(произвольное количество любых символов)XX"

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно составить регулярное выражение вида:

```
'ZZ(тут произвольное количество любых символов)XX'
```

Нужно найти первое вхождение этого шаблона в текст, допустим:

```
'df q ZZtp ot03-#3 rer#RXX df;l,gm XXpo45ZZ dsfdfdscv'
```

В данном случае нужна вот эта подстрока `'ZZtp ot03-#3 rer#RXX'`.

Регулярка типа:

```
re.findall(r'ZZ.+XX', 'df q ZZtp ot03-#3 rer#RXX df;l,gm XXpo45ZZ dsfdfdscv')
```

находит наибольшую подстроку `'ZZtp ot03-#3 rer#RXX df;l,gm XX'`, это мне не подходит.

Comment: Смягчите квантификатор, поставив после него знак вопроса `r'ZZ.+?XX'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте нежадное выражение, т.е. `ZZ.+?XX`

**О жадности**

Регулярные выражения по умолчанию "жадные", т.е. захватывают наибольшее возможное число символов.
Эта проблема была ещё со времён регулярных выражений POSIX.
Пример:
Регулярное выражение: `\".+\"`.
Текст: `Просто "что-то", но "в кавычках". А это - без них.`.
Тогда совпадение будет одно: `"что-то", но "в кавычках"`
Если нам нужны все выражения в кавычках, это нам не подходит.

**Как этого избежать**

После операторов `+`, `*`, `?` и `{}` можно поставить `?`, тогда жадность отключится.
Например, в том же тексте будут два совпадения: `"что-то"` и `"в кавычках"`, если регулярное выражение будет: `\".+?\"`, т.е.:

1. Кавычка
2. Хотя бы один символ, но чем меньше, тем лучше.
3. Кавычка.

**Ещё один метод**

Т.к. мы знаем, что в выражении в кавычках их не может быть(кроме первой и последней), мы можем написать так:
`\"[^"]+\"`.
Так мы обойдёмся без отключения жадности.

Comment: Добавлю, что второй метод быстрее, так что при прочих равных стоит использовать его.